# Show that there is $s \in [0, 1]$ such that no $(s, s/n)$ lays on a circle of radius from a closed boundary set in $[0, 1]$

Tags: general-topology

This is a homework exercise that I have problems solving:
Let $B \subset [0,1]$ be a closed boundary set in $[0,1]$ (by boundary set here I mean a set with an empty interior).
a) Prove that there is $s \in [0,1]$ such that the following is satisfied:
$*)$ for no positive integral number $n$, $(s, \frac sn)$ lays on a circle centered in $(0, 0)$ with a radius in $B$.
b) Prove that there is $s$ satisfying $(*)$ that is not rational.

Looking at b) I concluded that it must be easier to prove existence of a rational $s$.
Let's look at the equation we don't want $s$ to satisfy:
$$s^2 + (\frac sn)^2 = r^2$$ where $r \in B$. Rearranged this turns into:
$$s = \frac {rn}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}}$$
If I could prove that $s$ satisfying this has to be irrational, it would be a solution to the exercise. $\sqrt{n^2 + 1}$ is obviously irrational, but I can't see how to prove that the entire quotient is irrational as well.

Comment: What is a closed boundary set? The boundary of every set is closed.

Comment: @Presumably the emphasis is on *boundary set*. I would have said that $B$ is a closed, nowhere dense subset of $[0,1]$.

Comment: This might be a translation error on my side, by boundary set I mean a set with an empty interior.

Comment: @Marek: I suspected as much. The usual English description of the kind of set that you want is the one in my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$U_n=\left\{\frac{nr}{\sqrt{n^2+1}}\in\left[0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right]:r\in[0,1]\setminus B\right\}\;.$$

Show that each $U_n$ is a dense open subset of $\left[0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right]$, and apply the Baire category theorem. This will take care of (a), but you won’t know whether the numbers $s$ that you get are rational or irrational. To take care of (b), let $\{q_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+$ be an enumeration of the rationals in $\left[0,\frac1{\sqrt2}\right]$, and replace $U_n$ by $U_n\setminus\{q_n\}$.